# How to draw and route path in leaflet.js non-geographical map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dc.leaflet.js

I have used leaflet.js to built a non geographic map using [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system)

On top of this i have used leaflet draw control to manually draw lineString and then later saving them into mysql.

[image]

From the eg image above where path1, path2, path3 are different multiPoint lineString.

I wanted to know if it's possible to

1. find path between point A->B, B->A, A->C, C->A respectively, as its not gonna be a single lineString but combination of more than one depending where they intersect and if the intersecting line going towards the destination.
2. If A->D find the shortest route.

Comment: any luck with this? I am also thinking of using pgRouting

Comment: @BogdanMirceaStanciu Sorry for the late reply, yes i finally figured it out myself with help of pgRouting and QGIS.

Comment: No problem, what's funny is that just last night I had a breakthrough and managed to route using pgRouting. Now I will carry on with django and leaflet.